# Who know the meanings of state of CronTrigger object?

Tags: soap-api

Who know the meanings of state of CronTrigger object?
I wanna know the detail of those state and it is the best if answer from official documents.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation isn't clear, as far as I can tell, but I'll start an answer and see if anyone can fill in the blanks:

### WAITING

The job is queued to be executed at some point in the future.

### ACQUIRED

The necessary row/table locks have been acquired, and the job is about to start.

### EXECUTING

The job is currently processing.

### COMPLETE

The job has finished.

### BLOCKED

The job can't acquire locks and so has to wait.

### ERROR

The job failed (opposite of COMPLETE) and must be retried.

### PAUSED

The job has been suspended by the system to process other jobs.

### PAUSED_BLOCKED

The job has been suspended because of row locks, and will resume later.

### DELETED

The job has been aborted through some API command at the request of a user.

Comment: I referred to the documentation here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm , here the explanation for the "Complete" state is : The trigger has fired and is not scheduled to fire again. 
I can not understand the match between the explanation you provided for this status and the one that is given in documentation. Please explain ! @sfdcfoc

Answer (score 1):

> The Status column lists the current status of the job. The possible
> values are:
>
> **Holding** -    Job has been submitted and is held until system resources are freed up.
>
> **Queued** -     Job is awaiting execution.
>
> **Preparing** -   The start method of the job has been invoked. This status might last a few minutes depending on the size of the batch of records.
>
> **Processing** -  Job is being processed. Aborted Job was aborted by a user.
>
> **Completed** -   Job completed with or without failures.
>
> **Failed** -  Job experienced a system failure.

find more in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_apex_job.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: Hi Pavel, thank you for answer. Perhaps you confuse the object name form my question. Your answer refered to the AsyncApexJob object, I refered to the CronTrigger object. :) and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As per [salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm), below are the meanings for them:

- **WAITING**: The job is waiting for execution.
- **ACQUIRED**: The job has been picked up by the system and is about to execute.
- **EXECUTING**: The job is executing.
- **COMPLETE**: The trigger has fired and is not scheduled to fire again.
- **ERROR**: The trigger definition has an error.
- **DELETED**: The job has been deleted.
- **PAUSED**: A job can have this state during patch and major releases. After the release has finished, the job state is automatically set to WAITING or another state.
- **BLOCKED**: Execution of a second instance of the job is attempted while one instance is running. This state lasts until the first job instance is completed.
- **PAUSED_BLOCKED**: A job has this state due to a release occurring. When
  the release has finished and no other instance of the job is running,
  the job’s status is set to another state.